# 'charAt' 'for loop' issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, char

I put `charAt()` inside a for loop to take the characters entered in an input box`inp` and display the output in textarea `outp`.

```
var inp = document.getElementById('inp').value;
var outp = document.getElementById('display');
for(x = 0;x<inp.length;x++){
    var res = inp.charAt(x);
    outp.innerHTML = res + "\n";
}
```

For some reason it only prints the last character in the input, instead of printing every letter of the input. I'm guessing that it's the nature of charAt or there's something wrong with the loop.

I Felt that it just replaced the character so I even inserted a line break but doesn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Append don't replace: `outp.innerHTML += res + '\n';` (also note uppercase `L`)

Comment: You are replacing output. You need to append

Comment: Also, `innerHTML` not `innerHTMl`

Comment: Also, better update `innerHTML` once, not in a loop. Apply the logic to a string variable first, probably best with `split` and `join`.

Comment: or just `outp.innerHTML = inp.split('').join('\n');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing that because you are printing `x` and `x` is always the most current loop index and you are setting the `innerHTML` to just that one character. You need to concatenate that character to the end of the previous string.

You also have a typo with `innerHTML`. You wrote `innerHTMl`. And, regarding that, don't use `.innerHTML` when you won't be adding HTML in the first place, use `textContent` instead in situations like that because there is more performance overhead to using `innerHTML` than `textContent`.

```js
// Don't set your variables to a property of a DOM element. Set them to the 
// element itself. This way, if you ever need a different proeprty value, you
// won't have to re-scan the DOM for the same element again.
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var outp = document.getElementById('display');


var output = ""; // This will hold the built up string

for(x = 0; x < inp.value.length;x++){
    var res = inp.value.charAt(x);
    output += res + "\n";  // concatenate with +=
}

outp.textContent = output; // update the dom as little as possible
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="ABCDEFG">
<div id="display"></div>
```